Short exact sequences of orthonormal frame bundles
Given an orthonormal $l$-frame bundle $V_l(TM)\rightarrow M$ for a smooth (oriented) $d$-manifold $M$, there are short exact sequences on homotopy groups

$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \pi_{d-l}(V_l(TM))\rightarrow \pi_{d-l}(M)$ in the case of $d-l$ even and
$\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow \pi_{d-l}(V_l(TM))\rightarrow \pi_{d-l}(M)$ in the case of $d-l$ odd and not equal to $1$, $3$ or $7$ (which comes from these spheres being parallelizable).

This partially stems from the fact that the first non-vanishing homotopy group of $V_l(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is precisely $\pi_{d-l}$ and is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $d-l$ even (or $l=1$) and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ otherwise (Lemma 3.20 in Hatcher's book on $K$-theory and vector bundles).
My question is: Is it known whether these sequences split, or under which circumstances? If so, does someone has a reference?
